# How to remove (customize) the color of the bar from global-display-line-numbers-mode?

Tags: line-numbers, global-mode, side-bar

I want to use relative line numbers and therefore I turned on this mode:
**Global Display Line Numbers Mode**. When I want to customize this variable, there is no option in customizing the color of the bar or remove it entirely. How do I achieve this?

It looks like this:

[image: line number bar]

Thanks for any help in advance :^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The face that are used for line numbers are `line-number` and `line-number-current-line`. Customizing the background color of these faces might be your solution. You may also need to deal with the `fringe` face. [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Basic-Windows.html#index-window_002dvalid_002dp) is more information about margins and fringes.

I did not understand what you mean by "remove it entirely", I guess turning off `display-line-numbers-mode` does the job.

Comment: That is what I was looking for.  thanks